# How do I deal with Git lfs problems

Tags: git

I am working on my repo on a few computers. I usually sync around them. But suddenly, my file is converted to something like:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
<<<<<<< HEAD
oid sha256:02daf7523403e931af3b42121534efb04ab55b7d31e865756741ed9
size 350681
=======
oid sha256:ab76951235164345311cc280d143ed3465463453ea340
size 149339
>>>>>>> 344747cdojdu2091239hh59a97e913038ee
```

What shall i do to get the original file? Thanks